# can't interpret PHP on RHEL + nginx

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I'm doing the following steps and can't seem to have the PHP interpreted. I've done many variants of this, searched the web extensively and shown it to a friend: we don't understand what we do wrong. Could you help?

1. Launch RHEL 7.3 Amazon free tier instance
2. Connect in SSH with mac Terminal app

   ```
   sudo yum install wget
   wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
   sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release-latest-7*.rpm
   sudo yum install nginx
   sudo service nginx restart
   ```
3. open port 80 in rehl instance inbound rules
4. check http://[my_instance_name].eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/, it displays the welcome to nginx on Fedora page
5. install php and configure nginx

```
sudo yum install php-fpm
sudo yum install nano
sudo nano /etc/php.ini, and in the file, set cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, and set the worker processes to 4 (value was: auto)
sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf and have the following conf:

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name localhost;


        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.php  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

6. configure php

```
sudo nano /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf and confirm user and group are php-fpm
sudo service php-fpm restart
sudo nano /usr/share/nginx/html/info.php containing phpinfo(); (with the php tags, stackoverflow seems to hide it)
sudo service nginx restart
sudo chkconfig --levels 235 nginx on
sudo chkconfig --levels 235 php-fpm on
```

7. browse to http://[my_instance_name].eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/info.php : it downloads the php file instead of interpreting it
8. change step /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf and say that user and group are nginx, restart nginx, php file still downloaded instead of interpreted
9. change step /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf and say server_name = [IP of my instance], restart nginx, php file still downloaded instead of interpreted

What am I missing?

Comment: server_name localhost; ?

Comment: Hi there, also tried with server_name = my AWS IP, no more luck. Was that what you're pointing to?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2):

First of all check logs at /var/log/nginx and /var/log/php-fpm

Second, Check using `netstat -lnp` that php-fpm do listen on port 9000

Third, This is the nginx configuration that works for me:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Hi there,
Thanks so much for the help.
1. Both log files are empty (as in, they don't even exist). Is that normal?
2. php-fpm does listen:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9638/php-fpm: maste 

3. replaced my location directive with yours, restarted nginx, still downloads and doesnt interpret

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the short php open tags,`<?` ? If so, double check that `short_open_tag` in your php.ini is enabled, as it's not enabled by default on some distributions.

It might be that it actually /is/ working, but that PHP is not seeing any 'php code'.